403 from Azure only in a specific endpoint with specific version of the API
We developed a middleware service Web API app in .NET 6 with several endpoints and deployed it to Azure. We get a strange error with an endpoint that implements a POST method.
If we change the version of the endpoint from v2.1 to v3, Azure returns a http 403 error - it works perfectly in local environment.
To recap:
{{Baseurl}}/bookings/api/v2.1/checkout/nexi -> Status Code: 200 Ok
{{Baseurl}}/bookings/api/v3/checkout/nexi -> Status Code: 403 Forbidden

In the controller we have updated just the version no other changes are present.
How is it possible that azure stop the request on V3 version of the API? All endpoints, except this one, work perfectly.
We found out that the problem was an object in the request but we still don't understand why this is a problem only with v3 version of the endpoint

403 means that the user is logged in but not allowed to do certain things, as you surely know. What is "Ko" in your question (after the link)? I'd also investigate if other endpoints start failing the same way when you change the URL to version 3. Is so, you may have a gateway, load balancer or such that won't allow that pattern somehow.

Thank you for the reply. It is only this endpoint that has the problem in V3 but I didn't try to call the others endpoint with the request that cause the incriminated endpoint to throw the 403. ko means that the request didn't give the expected response

I see. You will need to do the call I asked about in order to get more diagnostics. Otherwise, there's a risk that you won't get much help from the community. And you also risk getting bashed (not rarely in a unnecessarily harsh way). As far I can guess based on the limited information, there's something in your local setup that is configured differently than usually. I'll post an answer but I'm not sure I'm on the right path.

Disclaimer
There's only limited information available and, at this point, there's no diagnostics on how other endpoints would behave with the changed route. Hence, all the below is a guesstimation and may very well be entirely irrelevant and misleading.
I note two things. First being that it seems to behave expectedly on your local system (and as far my experience goes, so does it on a server in a general case). So your specific hosting environment is a suspect here.
Second thing is the uncommon status code: 403 ko. It gives me sensation of a smelly concept because it should be 403 Forbidden, which means that the user is identified (has logged in, hence no 401 Unauthorized).
So my **guess*timation is that whoever set up your hosting (the infra dudes, devops or whoever governs the server environments at your place), made a boo-boo and somehow prevented certain patterns to be forwarded to the application.
This may be due to load balancer settings, docker orchestration, gateway configuration and, possibly, a bunch of other weird places that a developer should know of but will unwillingly horse around with.
Do you have access to those properties of your server environment? Or, at least, can you talk to someone who does?
I'd start looking into Azure's gateway and its traffic redirection.

Sorry I wasn't clear about the status. The status is: 403 Forbidden
Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2.

@oiradIta Good to hear. However, just to be nit-picky: the Status Code is 403 Forbidden, not 403 Forbidden Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2. Additionally, what you just wrote suggests even more that there  may be a config in the gateway that matches on regex like .*/v2/.* or possibly .*/v[0-9]*/.* which makes your new path (containing a dot and/or not being v2 verbatim) rejected. To confirm that theory, try an endpoint with /v3/. Either way, it seems to be something with the config of the gateway. Can you share more details about that?

@oiradIta Any update on the situation?

Sorry for my absence, yes the problem has been solved. I contacted the administrator of the azure's server environment and it turned out that there was a an exception RequestLenght for the url {{Baseurl}}/bookings/api/v2.1/checkout/nexi in order to make the request to pass. We have set the exception for v3 url too and now it works perfectly.
Thank you so much for helping me

Glad to hear that. So in the end, I was not far off in my gut feeling. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted and/or upvote if you appreciated it.
